# Joomla 1.5 - is enough 48MB memory in PHP settings?

Tags: php, joomla

Joomla 1.5 - is enough 48MB memory in PHP settings ? or is better at least 64MB ?

I ask because sometime is realy slow respond.

Merax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

48 MB should be fine. Different from operating systems and classical applications that swap memory, increasing the memory limit in PHP will very rarely improve performance: If the memory limit is hit, the script usually simply crashes.

The reasons for the slowness of your site is most likely elsewhere, maybe on server level, maybe inside the Joomla application.

You may find the best resources on that in the Joomla community, which is very active. Googling turns up [joomlaperformance.com](http://www.joomlaperformance.com) which seems to have some articles.

Comment: from my experience. 48 MB is more than enough... however If you are planning to have image manipulation in your PHP scripts (gallery or community albums), I would recommend using more memory.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla is designed to run on the default 8M of memory that PHP.ini by default provides.